# Equilateral 0r isoceles triangle from three die throws

Tags: probability

Let the sides of a triangle be decided throwing a die thrice. If the probability that the triangle is isosceles or equilateral is p/q, where p and q are relatively prime positive integers, then q-p is?

My approach is, no of equilateral triangle = $6$

No of isosceles but not equilateral
For an isosceles △, we have $(2,2,1)(2,2,3)\\(3,3,1)(3,3,2)(3,3,4)(3,3,5)\\(4,4,1)(4,4,2)(4,4,3)(4,4,5)(4,4,6)\\(5,5,1),(5,5,2)(5,5,3)(5,5,4)(5,5,6)\\(6,6,1)(6,6,2),(6,6,3)(6,6,4)(6,6,5)\times3= 21\times3=63$

No of scalene triangles formed from $(2,3,4),(2,4,5),(2,5,6),(3,4,5),(3,4,6),(3,5,6),(4,5,6)=7*3!=42$

Thus, required probability is=$\frac{6+63}{6+63+42}=\frac{23}{37}$
Hence, $q-p=14$, but answer is single digit positive integer. I wish to know if I left any case?

Comment: I believe that each unique triangle has been  counted only once, (ie not permuted), thus $q-p = 34 - 27 =7$